# Why does JavaScript use base 10 floating point numbers (according to w3schools)?

Tags: javascript

I read this [on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_number.asp):

> All numbers in JavaScript are stored as 64-bit (8-bytes) base 10,
>   floating point numbers.

This sounds quite strange. Now, it's either wrong or there should be a good reason not to use base 2 like the IEEE standard.

I tried to find a real JavaScript definition, but I couldn't find any. Either on the V8 or WebKit documentation, the two JavaScript implementation I could find on Wikipedia that sounded the most familiar to me, I could find how they stored the JavaScript Number type.

So, does JavaScript use base 10? If so, why? The only reason I could come up with was that maybe using base 10 has an advantage when you want to be able to accurately store integers as well as floating point numbers, but I don't know how using base 10 would have an advantage for that myself.

Comment: **w3schools is not W3C** (and is full of mistakes or at least imprecise  (http://w3fools.com/)). If you want to know how numbers are represented, have a look at the specification: http://es5.github.com/#x8.5.

Comment: Official link: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/.

Comment: If, this thing W3Schools claims, someone claimed here, he would get downvoted to oblivion without hesitation.

Comment: Awww, ok I didn't even notice it was w3schools, sorry. Someone handed me the link and I read wrong. Tbh, I always thought the two were related, but seemingly it's not (as I can't find any W3C reference on w3schools.com).
Explains a lot!

Comment: This is why **we do not use w3schools as a resource**

Comment: `I always thought the two were related` that's what they're counting on. I'd be surprised if the authors of that site even knew what "base" means...

Comment: @phant0m: I'm sure they're painfully aware that they never passed the first one

Comment: @phant0m: [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball_metaphors_for_sex)

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel I meant to ask what you mean by "the first one". Do you mean that they failed at people thinking they're related?

Comment: @phant0m: Follow the link I gave you. Then read our comment conversation again. :)

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel Oh, that was a link. I hate SO's `:visited`... That's why I always boldface all links.

Comment: @phant0m you can always add a userscript / userstyle. BTW, is there a good userstyle manager for Chrome?

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh right... I still [**have a script**](http://stackapps.com/questions/2808/stackexchange-theme-switcher) that lets me choose a different theme for SE sites. Thanks for reminding me :) As for the latter, I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: @phant0m P.S. I'm aware that greasemonkey/tampermonkey can manage userscripts as well, but there's the overhead of `document.head. ...`

Comment: @JanDvorak I've never heard about that. Can you link me? (overhead + `document.head`)

Comment: @phant0m the idea is to inject some HTML into the head with a user-script: `document.head.innerHTML+="<style>a{font-weight:bold}"` (don't worry, the browser will close your HTML `:-)` )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not the [World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/), that's w3schools, a website that isn't any authority for any web standards.

Numbers in Javascript are double precision floating point numbers, following the IEEE standards.

The site got the part about every number is a 64-bit floating point number right. The base 10 has nothing with the numerical representation to do, that probably comes from the fact that floating point numbers are always parsed and formatted using base 10.

Answer (score 5):

Numbers in JavaScript are, according to the ECMA-262 Standard (ECMAScript 5.1) [section 4.3.19](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19):

> Primitive values corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format **IEEE 754** value.

Thus, any implementation using base 10 floating point numbers is not ECMA-262 conformant.

Comment: Thank you for the edit (I didn't manage to put bold within the blockquote). However, authoritativity didn't seem to have been important here :)

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript uses, like most modern languages, [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985). Which isn't at all stored in base 10.

The specificity of JavaScript is that there is only one number type, which is the double precision float. Which has the side effect that you're somewhat limited contrary to other languages if you want to deal with integers : you can't store any double precision integer, only the ones fitting in the size of the fraction (52 bits).

Comment: That is, with binary exponent (and exponent base) and mantissa

Comment: *"The specificity of **java** is..."* ? :)

Comment: @FelixKling Most languages deal with ints in int32 or int64 formats. Edit : oooops... ^^

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you wrote `java` instead of `javascript`. I could have edited but I did not want to cancel your 5min grace period ;)

Comment: @JanDvorak "and exponent base"?

Comment: @phant0m in `x^y*z`, `x` is the base, `y` is the exponent and `z` is mantissa.

Comment: @JanDvorak That, I do know, but I don't know why you mentioned it. The base isn't stored, after all. But, you know that too, so my interpretation may be all wrong.

Comment: @phant0m my point is that the base is `2` (not stored in binary; sorry), not `10`.